# My layout constraints are causing errors when buttons are added to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm trying to make an app for iOS with a keyboard and a couple of buttons. My keyboard is one big view. So I added that first to my storyboard and set a leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint that are anchored to the safe area as so as well as a fixed width and height:

[image]

and it looks great on any screen but then as soon as I add a couple of buttons everything goes out of wack

[image]

That's how it looks when I switch from iPhone 8 to iPhone 8 plus.

Each button has a fixed width of 60, height of 45, all but the first and last button have their leading constraints anchored to the button on the left.

Here is an image with all my current constraints

[image]

I've followed along with what most tutorials and articles do when it comes to auto layout and I'm this point I really don't know what I'm doing.

Here are the errors

[image]

I would appreciate any help and advice on how to fix this issue. Thank you!

Comment: What are the errors that are being shown.

Comment: @Paulw11 The errors are missing constraints for Y position or height which I don't understand because I have constraints for height for all my buttons and the keyboard view. Also just added a picture of the missing constraints.

Comment: Why is your keyboard anchored on all 4 edges and have its height/width set?  If you set height and width then you should only constrain 2 edges or perhaps set the centerX and centerY

Comment: From my understanding I thought you are suppose to have all four edges constrained. So if I set two constrain edges, leading and trailing, is that enough to tell Xcode that I want it to stretch horizontally on each side?

Comment: If you have all four edges constrained then you shouldn’t  constrain the width and height since the width and height is implied by the edge constraints and the superview size. What is important ? The size of the keyboard or the distance to the edges? If the size is important the constrain the width and height and constain the view to, say, the center of the superview. If the edge distance is important then constrain the edges and let autolayout adjust the size of the image. Or you could set the size and constrain just one edge in each axis

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok I followed your advice and it worked for the keyboard however the buttons are still giving me trouble. I set the top and bottom edge constraints for the buttons but then as soon as I set the far left button to have a leading edge constraint, it just gets pushed off to the right. I then try to make it have fixed widths and am able to set all the leading edge constraints but when I change phone screen size half of the buttons are off the screen because of the fixed width constraint

Comment: If you want the buttons to auto size and auto distribute then it is probably easiest with a stackview. You could also try constraining the leading edge of the first button to the leading edge of hr superview, the leading edge of the second button to the trailing edge of the first and so on until you get to the last button where you constrain its trailing edge to the trailing edge of the superview and the set all of the buttons to have an equal width to the first button

Comment: @Paulw11 wow that worked, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way for me to give you best answer? I just noticed that we basically had a discussion

Comment: I will add an answer a bit later and then you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you want the buttons to auto size and auto distribute then it is probably easiest with a `IUStackView`.

Another approach is to constrain the leading edge of the first button to the leading edge of the superview (or the leading edge of your keyboard view if you want to align the buttons with the keyboard).

Then constrain the leading edge of the second button to the trailing edge of the first and so on until you get to the last button where you constrain its trailing edge to the trailing edge of the superview (or keyboard view)

Finally, the set all of the buttons to have an equal width to the first button.  You will now have a fixed spacing between buttons and equal-but-variable sized buttons